# How to implode the foreach loop values?

Tags: php, implode

I am trying to implode the for each loop to get results like this

```
           ["86","87","88"]
```

Code I am using to achieve results as follows

```
           $tags = [];

            $tagsData = $this->Constant_model->getDataOneColumn('snippets_tags', 'snippet_id', $id);

            foreach ($tagsData as $data) {

             $tag_data = $data->tag_id;

              array_push($tags, $tag_data );

            }
```

Comment: That looks like JSON, use `json_encode($tags)`

Comment: No idea can you please solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `json_encode()` to output that format:

```
echo json_encode($tags);
```

Comment: I am getting white space in first element.. how to remove that?

Comment: You can use `$tags = array_filter($tags)` this will remove all empty elements from the original array. before echo, statement add the above line.

Comment: @UpasanaChauhan Or check whether `$tag_data` is empty before pushing it onto the array.

Answer (score 0):

`implode` will change your data to a string.

```
$arr = ['1', '2', '3'];
$imp = implode(', ', $arr);
echo $imp; // output: 1, 2, 3
```

Probably, what you want is -

```
$tags = [];

$tagsData = $this->Constant_model->getDataOneColumn('snippets_tags', 'snippet_id', $id);

foreach ($tagsData as $data) {

    $tags[] = $data->tag_id;

}
```

Hope it helps you. :)

Comment: I don't see the difference. All you did was get rid of the intermediate variable, and use `$tags[]` instead of `array_push()`, but they're equivalent.